# Calling curl from Python - stderr is different from when running on the commend line. Why?

Tags: python, curl, subprocess

When running curl on the command line against a domain that doesn't exist, I get an error message as expected

```
$ curl https://doesnoexist.test/
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: doesnoexist.test
```

But if I do the same thing from Python, printing the standard error

```py
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['curl', 'https://doesnoexist.test/'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
outs, errs = proc.communicate()
print(errs)
```

then I get the the start of what seems to be a download progress indicator, and then the same error message right after

```
$ python curl.py
b'  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  
Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent 
   Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--
 --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: doesnoexist.test\n'
```

Why? How can I only get the error message in Python?

(Ideally answers won't just be for curl, but more general where similar things happen when running other processes)

Comment: the meter is printed in both cases, but in a tty (terminal) you can erase the meter and all of the data and just keep the error message, this won't work if the output is going into a buffer, for example you can redirect `curl` stderr to a file and you will get the same output as python, unfortunately going the other way is not so easy, as you can't make a buffer act like a tty unless you manually process it as a tty would do (for example handling carrige returns without a new line to rewrite lines).

Comment: @AhmedAEK "unless you manually process it as a tty would do" interesting... what would this involve? Is it that difficult? Is it just the carriage return without a newline thing, or is there more? (I am very ignorant of this...)

Comment: it is basically rewriting a terminal emulator ... you could probably find an "in memory terminal emulator" to redirect the app output to and get the "formatted final output", but i haven't tried any of these before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially `curl` seems to test whether `stdout` is connected to a tty (ie. whether it is interactive, essentially it does the equivalent of `sys.stdout.isatty()`) and if it isn't add a progress meter by default (which makes sense, since then the output will not mingle with stderr on the terminal).

You can test this directly in the shell by comparing what you get with redirection to `output`

```bash
$ curl https://test.doestaa > output
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: test.doestaa
```

and without

```bash
$ curl https://test.doestaa
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: test.doestaa
```

In python this means you could now just leave stdout alone:

```py
from subprocess import run, PIPE
proc = run(["curl", "https//test.doestaa/"], stderr=PIPE)
print(proc.stderr)
```

to get the same effect, but without the possibility to get to its output.

Or you would have to set up a pty and connect it there like with [ptyprocess](https://ptyprocess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but you should indeed just use curl's `--no-progress-meter` flag or consider using a python http client like the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [HTTPX](https://www.python-httpx.org/) libraries, instead.

Comment: Ah thanks! Sounds like there probably isn't a one-size-fits-all solution for all programs alas (other than going for ptyprocess/similar, but for my purposes that's overkill...)